# PrimeNG autocomplete changes the Form data model

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I've encountered some strange behaviour with PrimeNG 7.0.0 and the Autocomplete component. Summary of this problem is that whatever the structure of my source JSON object is in it overwrites my FormGroup model with this structure when an item is selected.

My FormGroup objects looks like:

```
exportCountry: this.fb.group({
          id: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(2)]    //  5/14    a2 UPPERCASE
        }),
```

This produces JSON of:

```
{
"exportCountry": {
        "id": ""
      },
}
```

My source JSON for suggestions looks like this:

```
{"countries":
[
  {
    "code": "FR",
    "name": "FRANCE"
  },
  {
    "code": "AD",
    "name": "ANDORRA"
  },
  {
    "code": "AE",
    "name": "UNITED ARAB EMIRATES"
  },.....................
]
}
```

I have a component which includes the autoComplete component:

```
<div formGroupName="exportCountry">
  <p-autoComplete [suggestions]="filteredCountriesSingle" [inputId]="type+'countryId'"
                  (completeMethod)="filterCountrySingle($event)" field="code" 
                  [minLength]="1" [inputStyleClass]="'form-control'"
                  formControlName="id">

    <ng-template let-country pTemplate="item">
      <div class="ui-helper-clearfix" style="width: 20em">
        <span>{{country.code}}</span>
        <span> - </span>
        <span>{{country.name}}</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-autoComplete>
</div>
```

The .ts file basically follows the example on PrimeNG showcase and this all displays correctly and filters and shows the correct suggestions.  However once an item is selected from the options my FormGroup object/JSON changes to:

```
"exportCountry": {
        "id": {
          "code": "FR",
          "name": "FRANCE"
        }
      },
```

I require that the selected Code is set against the FormControl originally assigned i.e.

```
{
"exportCountry": {
        "id": "FR"
      },
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide a stackblitz ?

Comment: Stackblitz here but work in progres as unable to get suggestions to show.[link]https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-autocomplete-btqj7h?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Stackblitz now working and shows how the json object is changed upon selected a suggestion.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @Gemasoft I had to use a `mat-autocomplete` which kept the JSON structure.